# How can I draw in unicode with artist-mode?

Tags: unicode

I'd like to produce unicode art with artist-mode. But it appears that artist-mode only supports ASCII art.

How can I configure artist-mode to produce instead of

```
  +---------------+
  |               |
  |       +-------+--+
  |       |       |  |
  |       |       |  |
  |       |       |  |
  +-------+-------+  |
          |          |
          |          |
          |          |
          +----------+
```

this

```
  ┌───────────────┐
  │               │
  │       ┌───────┼──┐
  │       │       │  │
  │       │       │  │
  │       │       │  │
  └───────┼───────┘  │
          │          │
          │          │
          │          │
          └──────────┘
```

Comment: I actually read "how can I draw a unicorn with artist-mode" :-) unicode makes so much more sense...  The characters are actually hardcoded, you would have to fork artist.el and replace/adapt the (XXX-char) functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nice package by [TTN](http://gnuvola.org) called [aau2](http://www.gnuvola.org/software/aa2u/) which is available in GNU ELPA.

I tried to test it. result is nice as you expected.

```
M-x package-install RET ascii-art-to-unicode RET
\select region/
M-x aa2u RET
```

Edit: just for reference, here is mailing list link for an example.
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2014-05/msg00316.html

Comment: It seems that once aa2u has converted there is no way to reverse that. So if I've once converted to unicode, and I can not change the "art" with artist-mode. :(

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I could undo it by `C-/` and could change and draw as usual.

Comment: Sure but not if I have terminated the emacs session in between.

Comment: Hmm. a feature request to author I guess :/